# Swift: how to correctly rotate UITableViewController and UIViewController and in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

In my iOS app I want some controllers to have only `.Portrait` mode and moreore I would like them to rotate in `.Portrait` mode when coming from a controller allowed to be in `.Landscape` mode. I thought that implementing the following method in these `.Portrait` only view controllers was the right way:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")

}
```

Anyway the result I get is not correct. For example the following is a `.Portrait` only `UITableViewController` and when `viewWillAppear()` is called, instead of this

[image]

I instead get the following

[image]

This happens also with `UIViewController`. It's like the view (or the table view) is not rotated and remains in `.Landscape` mode. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you play with Auto-Layout? When I set leading edge, trailing edge everything goes right.

Another solution can be recalculate manually the textView:

```
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    textView.frame = CGRect(x: textView.frame.minY, y: textView.frame.minX, width: textView.frame.height, height: textView.frame.width)
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tested my previous solution and it doesn't work, but I found another way. Actually you need to rotate it and call viewWillAppear one more time - it works for me, try this:

```
if orientation.isLandscape{
   let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
   UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
   viewWillAppear(false)
}
```

No - it doesn't work for all cases...

I'm testing it like this:

1. I'm in app,
2. Mobile rotation to landscape, in tab bar item (where is not checked orientation). After that I tap on tab bar item where I checked orientation, and I rotate)
3. It rotates nicely without your problem, and when I'm doing it one more time the problem shows. But when I tap on another tab bar item and come back, everything goes right - I think we should call some method, I still don't know which one.

Comment: Yes, I used Auto-Layout and set many constraints. So, shall I implement the method you have written?

Comment: Give me a second I will test this idea and I tell you if I'm right

Comment: I think that I found a solution, but you have to try, I will edit my upper code.

Comment: I was making a silly mistake...I have just tried it but I get the same result, I'm sorry but maybe it does not work for me. Have you idea what the problem could be?

Comment: I was trying to find out something but I haven't found nothing interesting, I saw that when you are rotating you call method: viewWillTransitionToSize, maybe there you can do something, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069874/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-orientation-changes-in-ios-8 . Good luck!

Comment: I have just notice that the problems concerns the frame of the cell, in particular its width. So I store the original assigned width (the first time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called) and then in `viewWillAppear()` I just called `self.tableView.reloadData()` but this time the frame is read from the stored previous one...it seems to work. What do you think?