# Google Vision iOS Example: Scanned barcode Shape(purpleColor) shows in wrong location

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner, google-vision

I have downloaded the google vision api from https://github.com/googlesamples/ios-vision. And I tried Barcode detector example, When I try to scan a linear and 2D barcodes, the scanned area(purple shape) shows in wrong location on preview layer.

Note: This issue only occurs when I hold the device horizontally at the top of barcode.

Herewith I have attached the screenshot which reflects this issue.

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you!

Comment: What orientations does your app supports?

Answer (score 0):

We might need more details about how the framework you mentioned handles orientations. But 2 possible solutions I can think of are:

1) If your project only supports portrait mode, clearly specify it in the project settings. This often solves the orientation issues. (I had a similar one when using OpenCV's camera implementation)

[image]

2) If your project does support different orientations, you might have to handle orientations yourself for that specific view controller, something like this:

[What is the "right" way to handle orientation changes in iOS 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069874/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-orientation-changes-in-ios-8)